# Why doesn't the Julia compiler optimise this loop?

Tags: compiler-construction, compilation, julia

I know very little about compiling but I was surprised to see that Julia compiler doesn't optimize several processes.

Let's consider Julia (that is a *Just-in-Time* compiler) and let's consider these two pieces of code that do essentially the same thing.

```
n=1
@time for i = 1:10^8 n=n+1 end
elapsed time: 3.535394087 seconds (0 bytes allocated)

n=1
@time n=n+10^8
elapsed time: 6.599e-6 seconds (112 bytes allocated)
```

Why is a modern compiler not able to understand that this long loop will do nothing but adding `10^8` to `n`?

The following example is even more striking I think

```
n=1
@time for i = 1:10^9 n=n end
elapsed time: 3.496573198 seconds (0 bytes allocated)
```

Comment: It all depends on how much effort the developers of the compiler put into the optimizer. Some compilers in other languages *do* perform that optimization, actually.

Comment: Oh ok. I expected some fundamental limitations of how a code can be compiled. I think you can pretty much make an answer out of your comment (adding eventually a tiny bit of explanations of why it si a big work to construct compiler that can perform this optimization)

Comment: This is just a baseless generalization from a single example. -1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a problem when executing in global scope and is connected with optimizing under conditions where types could change, but given the right circumstances, the situation changes.  Constraining the evaluation within a function allows the compiler to do much more.  Consider the same thing but in a function.

```
function f(n::Int64)
   x = 0;
   for i = 1:n
      x = x + 1;
   end
   return x;
end


julia> @time f(100)
elapsed time: 2.93e-6 seconds (80 bytes allocated)
100

julia> @time f(Int64(1e11))
elapsed time: 4.632e-6 seconds (112 bytes allocated)
100000000000
```

By checking the compiler output using **code_native**, you can see that the loop is optimized out

```
julia> code_native(f,(Int64,)) 

Source line: 6
    push    RBP
    mov RBP, RSP
    test    RDI, RDI
    jg  L15
    xor EDI, EDI
Source line: 6
L15:    mov RAX, RDI 
    pop RBP
    ret
```

Comment: I understand why I have been told that it is good practice to encapsulate my code lines into functions in Julia. Thanks a lot for your answer +1

Comment: A comment on 'Constraining the evaluation within a function allows the compiler to do much more.' OK, but why? Well, for example if `n` is a global object, then some other proces or thread or whatever might be looking at it and monitor its growth. It can also be represent a piece of hardware. I know nothing about Julia but in some other environments you can declare a variable at a specific point in the address space, thus mapping it onto some physical device. Then the sequence of writes must not be 'optimized' because that might change the designed behavior of the system.